# is it possible to count the number of visitors on your asp.net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know it must be simple but i am new to web development, and i have developed a small asp.net web site with c#, and now I want to count the number of visits by unique IP addresses, how can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count Number of Visitors in WebSite using ASP.Net and C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508529/count-number-of-visitors-in-website-using-asp-net-and-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write something of your own, but you'd be better off setting up Google analytics or something similar on your site.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can roll your own method.  Or you can use something like google analytics.  What kind of method are you looking to do?

http://www.google.com/analytics/