# How do I count the number of visits to my site on a day with asp.net and sql server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

can any one give me a road-map for implementing the daily hit counter in asp.net
i know how to get total visitor but I have no idea about the implementation daily visitor counter

Comment: why dont you using something free and powerful as google analytics?

Comment: related to ur Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508529/count-number-of-visitors-in-website-using-asp-net-and-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

there are various methods .. you might have a Tabel named HitCounter with Date and Count as columns

Then you can go Global.asax and write some code Application_BeginRequest to first check Todays date in Date column and  update counter by incrementing it 1

But i would prefer free service such as google analytics 
or http://www.e-zeeinternet.com/